# making a realistic bracelet with gravity

Tags: modeling

my question today was pertaining making realistic bracelets and/or watches that could possibly move along the axis of the forearm of an avatar with gravity in mind. if you don't know what I mean imagine wearing a slightly over sized watch and it would slide up and down your fore-arm and wrist whenever your arm was pointed upwards. FYI im looking to get assets from gumroad and applying anything I learn from you guys in blender and exporting the avatar to unity for vrchat. I think making something like this would be truly revolutionary in VR

Comment: You could use two or three different physics simulation methods, but I’m not sure how well that would work in a VR system export.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *Physics > Rigid Body*. The bracelet will be set to *Type > Active, Shape > Mesh*, the cylinder will be set to *Type > Passive, Settings > Animated, Shape > Mesh*. Make the cylinder invisible and parent it to the same bone as the forearm:

[image]